# publishing fresh project on IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-8, vs-web-application-project

I have created new project web.net core without doing any changes and use the created default files. I can successfully run this using the debug mode, but if I am going to publish it on IIS it will give me error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error and here is the error details:

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Error code:

```
0x8007000d
```

I already tried to modify the web.config to point the processPath to my dotnet location but it still have the same error result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: d4e1dda9-f8ba-4752-883d-43c86faa3c60-->
```

I am not yet sure if this one is related to my IIS setup configuration. Any suggestion/comments if encountered this. TIA

Comment: You can find tons of duplicate threads on SO. I blogged about the bad things behind https://blog.lextudio.com/the-horrible-story-of-publishing-net-core-web-apps-for-beginners-6121662dd8c4

Answer (score 0):

check that under which application pool identity your site is running.
to check you could follow the below steps:

1)open iis manager.

2)select application pools and select your application pool name from the middle pane.

3)select the advance setting from the action pane.
[image]

then assign permission to the site folder.
1)open iis manager, select your site.

2)right-click on-site and select Edit permission.

[image]

3)In properties, windows select the security tab-> edit.

[image]

4)one pop up window will open in that select add.

[image]

5)in select user or group windows type "iusr" in object name text box and click ok and assign full permission.

[image]

6)Repeat the above steps and add "iis_iusrs" and "IIS AppPool\" user permission.

7)After doing changes restart the iis server.

You need to install the “ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle” on to the server.

you could also set load user profile to true in iis application pool advance setting.

[image]

please refer this below link for more detail:

[ASP.Net Core Publish: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error](https://forums.asp.net/t/2121840.aspx?ASP%20Net%20Core%20Publish%20HTTP%20Error%20500%2019%20Internal%20Server%20Error)

[500.19 error or 502.5 error when hosting asp.net core 2 application inside IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rohithrajan/2018/03/13/500-19-error-or-502-5-error-when-hosting-asp-net-core-2-application-inside-iis/)